# React how to generate multiple UUID on load (multiple tabs)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Trying to generate a UUID for each visitor who connects to my web app.

On development because of Hot reload, multiple tabs in the same browser will get a different UUID onload because all gets refresh together.

And because fetch takes a while, it ends up the localStorage gets overwritten with different UUID generated over the course of split of a second. And also my socket gets setname-ed to 3-4 different UUID.

In the production development because there's no hot reload, cases of this may be slim, but is there any best practice to avoid this?

```
componentWillMount() {
  if (localStorage.getItem('uuid') === null) {
    fetch('http://example.com/visitor/', {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Accept: 'application/json',
      },
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(jsondata => {
        localStorage.setItem('uuid', jsondata);
        this.setState({ socket: openSocket('http://localhost:3005') });
        this.state.socket('setname', this.state.userName);
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about generating `uuid` on the client side and push it to the backend then? You can use library like [uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) for this purpose

Comment: problem is all 3 will generate a different UUID right. WIll this happen in production environment?